# How do i see which smart packages i have installed within my meteor project?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

You can list available smart packages for installation for meteor by typing `meteor list` in the terminal. But what do i type in the terminal to see which smart packages i have installed in my meteor (or meteorite) project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correct, just add the `using` flag: `meteor list --using`

Answer (score 1):

cd into your project then:
$ cat .meteor/packages

Comment: This also does the trick and/"but" will give you some instructions for using packages.

Answer (score 1):

For meteorite look `smart.json` for smart packages `.meteor/packages`